# Разделить маркированный список

Tags: javascript

Есть маркированный список. Нужно его разбить на группы. По сути, зацепившись за заголовок, добавить над ним закрывающий тег `</ul>` и затем снова открыть. Но, на выходе получаем добавление перед пунктом с заголовком `<ul></ul>`. Как правильно закрыть и открыть список перед пунктом списка с классом `heading2` и `heading3`?

Код добавил для понимания ситуации и отображения текущей проблемы:

```js
let formField = document.querySelector('.form-field');
let heading = ['heading2', 'heading3'];
if (formField) {
  let allFields = [...document.querySelectorAll('.form-field')];
  allFields.forEach(el => {
    if (heading.some(heading => el.classList.contains(heading))) {
      el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '</ul><ul>');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="form-field heading1">Heading</li>
  <li class="form-field">1</li>
  <li class="form-field">2</li>
  <li class="form-field">3</li>
  <li class="form-field">4</li>
  <li class="form-field heading2">Heading</li>
  <li class="form-field">5</li>
  <li class="form-field">6</li>
  <li class="form-field">7</li>
  <li class="form-field heading3">Heading</li>
  <li class="form-field">8</li>
  <li class="form-field">9</li>
  <li class="form-field">10</li>
  <li class="form-field">11</li>
  <li class="form-field">12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А не проще ли пробежаться по дочерним LI и создать на их основе несколько UL-элементов, которые затем добавить вместо текущего UL? Дело в том, что в документации метода [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) сказано, что он парсит предоставленный код, после чего добавляет HTML-элементы, которые напарсил. Т.е. новый элемент добавить можно, а вот закрыть уже имеющийся никак.

Answer (score 1):

Изменим в соответствии с Вашим алгоритмом [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), а затем заменим родительский элемент.

```js
let ul = (formField = document.querySelector('.form-field')).parentElement;
let heading = ['heading2', 'heading3'];
if (formField) {
    let string = "</ul><ul>";
    let offset = string.length+1;
    let inner = "<ul>"+ul.innerHTML;
    let index = inner.indexOf('<li class="form-field heading', offset);
    while (index > -1) {
        inner = inner.slice(0, index) + string + inner.slice(index);
        index = inner.indexOf('<li class="form-field heading', (index+=offset));
    }
    ul.outerHTML = inner;
}
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="form-field heading1">Heading</li>
  <li class="form-field">1</li>
  <li class="form-field">2</li>
  <li class="form-field">3</li>
  <li class="form-field">4</li>
  <li class="form-field heading2">Heading</li>
  <li class="form-field">5</li>
  <li class="form-field">6</li>
  <li class="form-field">7</li>
  <li class="form-field heading3">Heading</li>
  <li class="form-field">8</li>
  <li class="form-field">9</li>
  <li class="form-field">10</li>
  <li class="form-field">11</li>
  <li class="form-field">12</li>
</ul>
```